# Why am I still getting a password prompt for git pull even after providing certificate and key

Tags: bash, ubuntu, configuration, git

I have added **http.sslCert** and **http.sslKey** in git global config file and set **http.sslVerify** to false but still getting password prompt for git pull. Tried googling for reasons but could not find anything related to it.

I am using HTTPS url to clone repository. Same setup works fine in Windows machine.

Below is the sample of my .gitconfig file

```
[user]
        name = my name
        email = my email
[http]
        sslCert = /some/path/certs/app.crt.pem
        sslKey = /some/path/certs/app.key.pem
        proxy = proxy_address:port
        sslVerify = false
```

Comment: You haven't told us how the remote is configured and what software it's using.  Usually most server installations require some sort of credentials even if you're using client certs.